# dbconnection class PGSQL rewrite function

Tags: php, postgresql, fetch

I'm currently writing a dbconnection class in PHP, using pgsql. I already write the connect and query function but I wondering how I can do to fetch the result.

Currently we need to use this function to fetch a result after a query :

```
$db = new dbconnection();
$stmt= $db -> query("SELECT * FROM users");
pg_fetch_all($stmt);
```

To have a cleaner code, I want to do the follow to fetch the result :

```
$db = new dbconnection();
$stmt= $db -> query("SELECT * FROM users");
$result = $stmt -> fetchAll();
```

Any help to how do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use PDO?

Comment: Oh right, thanks a lot :D

Comment: I post a simplified solution for your problem. Take a look ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `query` method of `dbconnection` should return an instance of `Statement` like so (PHP7, simplified):

```
final class Statement
{
    private $result;

    public function __construct(array $result = [])
    {
        $this->result = $result;
    }

    public function fetch()
    {
        return $this->result[0];
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

So you call this like so (simplified):

```
final class DBConnection
{
    // constructor etc.

    public function query(string $query)
    {
        // $result = result of the passed executed string $query

        return new Statement($result);
    }

}
```